# Передача атрибутов из цикла Thymeleaf

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, thymeleaf

Имеется контроллер, который выводит все департаменты. В html с помощью th:each Я вывожу их все. Это переменные Id, name доступны только внутри цикла. У меня ниже написано модальное окно в котором я могу отредактировать департамент (рядом с именем кнопка)

Так вот проблема в том, что мне нужно в модальное окно передать id департамента, но снаружи цикла его не видно. Как поступить?
Спасибо за любые советы

Comment: что насчет того, чтобы name стали глобальными?)

Comment: Я только за, если кинете линк или подсказку, буду очень благодарен

Comment: объявите просто name как поле класса

Comment: Лучше всего с помощью JS.

Comment: В таймлиф? Или контроллере?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема была решена с помощью JavaScript.
К кнопке добавил

`th:onclick="'javascript:showFunctionModal(\'' + ${department.id} +'\');'">`

И была добавлена функция

```
function showFunctionModal(id) {
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('.modal3').modal();
            $("#ids").val(id);
        });
```

Теперь она устанавливает значение с поля прямо мне в модалку, как я и хотел.